# Change date modified of multiple folders to match that of their most recently modified file

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I've been using the following shell bin/bash script as an app which I can drop a folder on, and it will update the date modified of the folder to match the most recently modified file in that folder.

```
for f in each "$@"
do
    echo "$f"
done
$HOME/setMod "$@"
```

This gets the folder name, and then passes it to this setMod script in my home folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check that exactly one parameter has been specified - the directory
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
   # Go to that directory or give up and die
   cd "$1" || exit 1
   # Get name of newest file
   newest=$(stat -f "%m:%N" * | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2 -d:)
   # Set modification date of folder to match
   touch -r "$newest" .
fi
```

However, if I drop more than one folder on it at a time, it won't work, and I can't figure out how to make it work with multiple folders at once.

Also, I learned from Apple Support that the reason so many of my folders keep getting the mod date updated is due to some Time Machine-related process, despite the fact I haven't touched some of them in years. If anyone knows of a way to prevent this from happening, or to somehow automatically periodically update the date modified of folders to match the date/time of the most-recently-modified file in them, that would save me from having to run this step manually pretty regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setMod` script current accepts only one parameter.
You could either make it accept many parameters and loop over them,
or you could make the calling script use a loop.

I take the second option, because the caller script has some mistakes and weak points. Here it is corrected and extended for your purpose:

```
for dir; do
    echo "$dir"
    "$HOME"/setMod "$dir"
done
```

Or to make `setMod` accept multiple parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

setMod() {
   cd "$1" || return 1
   # Get name of newest file
   newest=$(stat -f "%m:%N" * | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2 -d:)
   # Set modification date of folder to match
   touch -r "$newest" .
}

for dir; do
   if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
       echo not a directory, skipping: $dir
       continue
   fi

   (setMod "$dir")
done
```

Notes:

- `for dir; do` is equivalent to `for dir in "$@"; do`
- The parentheses around `(setMod "$dir")` make it run in a sub-shell, so that the script itself doesn't change the working directory, the effect of the `cd` operation is limited to the sub-shell within `(...)`

Comment: Brilliant! I love this community! That works like a charm. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Is there some way to modify this so that it will run recursively, drilling down to the lowest level of subfolders in any folder(s) I drop on the app, fixing the modified date on each of them, and then work its way up to the top level folder?

Also, will this script ignore .DS_Store files? Those are the files being updated by the OS and causing the folders' modification dates to be updated as well. I wish there was some way to simply prevent this from happening.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @MaxWell - I had this problem after iCloud reset all my folder dates. Here is a Python script that does my best attempt (ignoring .DS_Store, ignoring empty folders, otherwise taking dates from files, propogating up). In normal use folders actually only change date modified when a child file/folder is created or deleted, so I tried one based on ctime. But I preferred this mtime for my needs. ctime on existing folders will always be baised towards being too old because there is no record of stuff that was deleted. https://gist.github.com/robince/02f7613511b27279f9d661971ff880b7

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, this works well for me:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a REPLY; do
  echo touch -c -h -d@"${REPLY[0]}" "${REPLY[1]}"
  touch -c -h -d@"${REPLY[0]}" "${REPLY[1]}"
done < <(du "${1:-.}" --time-style=+%s --time | cut -f 2-)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.